# Solr: Next commit after rollback generates an exception

Tags: solr

After calling rollback, the next commit action will throw the following exception in my Solr (4.5.1):

```
SEVERE: null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1423)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1535)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1312)
at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:558)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processCommit(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:64)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processCommit(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1060)
at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:157)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:132)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader$SingleThreadedJsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:96)
at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:60)
at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:74)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1816)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:448)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:269)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
...
```

Any idea what's going on?